# Using an rasberrypi to make an bootable usb?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, raspbian, iso, bootable

my pc broke and i have an rasbery pi .
i want to write the iso of an recovery system (https://www.hirensbootcd.org) so i can repair my system more specific plan B
grabing the license key in the registry and downloading the windows iso .
i used dd if=...  of=...  it finishes with no errors but does not get recognized as a bootable usb

Comment: Does the computer you want to boot it up on is setup in UEFI mode?

Comment: @Paradox No my pc uses bios

Comment: This does not mean your BIOS does not support UEFI ; what you should look for is if your BIOS is set as using `legacy`, `UEFI` or both. If you're in legacy-mode, I think you might forget about doing so for this computer if it does not support UEFI booting since the Hiren FAQ does not say explicitly it supports non-UEFI mode : "Hiren’s BootCD PE supports UEFI booting from DVD and USB flash drives." BTW, your issue seems to be not Unix/Linux-related.

Comment: ok i asked this also on the rasbery pi forum . i will change to an linux system its the best thing i can do.Next weekend and it would be a performance boost .
Thanks :)